# wget / curl is not following the redirect of my URL

Tags: curl, wget

If you are on the [website](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues/89/pdf)  there is automatically started a download of pdf: https://magazines-static.raspberrypi.org/issues/full_pdfs/000/000/308/original/MagPi89.pdf?1576682030

I was writing to the MagPi magazine and they explained me, that the number 308 after the `full_pdfs/000/000/308` is a random number.

Long story short: I have to fix the issue on my downloader https://github.com/joergi/MagPiDownloader/issues/15 without copy pasting every single issue. So an automatic follow would be nice.

But everything i tried:

```
curl -JLO https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues/89/pdf
```

and

```
wget --user-agent=Mozilla --content-disposition -E -c https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues/80/pdf
```

was not working.

Comment: The page is using `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` to redirect to the actual pdf. You could `curl` the html document, then filter to get the actual pdf url.

Comment: can you maybe explain how to @thisaccounthasbeen ?

Comment: An example using awk to do the filtering: `curl -fsS "https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues/89/pdf" | awk -v 'RS=<' -F\> '/^meta http-equiv="refresh"/ && $1 ~ /url=/{split($1,a,"[?=\"]");exit} END{print "url=\""a[7]"\""}' | curl -f --remote-name-all -K-`

Comment: thx a lot. if you can write it as answer, I can accept it!

Comment: Your welcome. But I'm not really happy with it. Was hoping someone might have a much more elegant approach. Parsing html like this in scripts is asking for trouble down the road. You might consider moving to python (cross platform)

Comment: I don't really wanna move the complete project to Python... let's see....

Answer (score 1):

By examining the html from the site, it can be seen that the "[download pdf](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues/89/pdf)" links use a meta element with the http-eqiv="refresh" attribute to redirect to the real link. Whilst tools like `curl` or `wget` can handle standard [http redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), they don't parse or interpret html, and thus can't handle this type of redirect. As we're using a shell, one possible solution is to download the page using `curl` or `wget` and filter the html to see if it contains `http-eqiv="refresh"`.

---

As the site seems to have moved away from placing new editions to the accessible https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/ (nothing past issue #86 is there), it seems that the way your scripts currently work (ie. essentially a static database of pdf links) becomes counter-intuitive. The [special-issue-download script](https://github.com/joergi/MagPiDownloader/blob/master/linux_mac/magpi-special-issue-downloader.sh) looks to have the same bunch of pdfs as is listed at https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books, except the script is missing the most recent releases.

So I had a go at making a script that is a bit more dynamic. It looks at [/books](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books) & [/issues](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues) to see what's available/most recent. Your welcome to use any of it if you like – it uses `zsh`, `gawk` & `curl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
typeset -aU standard book ignore directory
typeset all latest list_books all_books baseurl="https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/"
setopt extendedglob
function books() {
    typeset -aU books filter minus
    typeset i
    >&2 echo "getting list of available books..."
    books=( $(2>/dev/null curl -fs ${baseurl}books | gawk -v 'RS=href="' -F '"' \
                                                    '$1 ~ /^[/]books[/][^/]*[/]pdf$/{split($1,a,"/"); print "books/"a[3]}') )
    if [[ -z $books ]]
    then
        >&2 echo "unable to find any books"
        return 0
    fi
    case $1 in
        (list)
            printf '\t%s\n' $books
            return 0
            ;;
        (all)
            >&2 echo "Attempting to download all the books, this may take a while ..."
            >&2 printf '\t%s\n' $books
            get_pdfs $books
            return 0
            ;;
        (*)
            for i in $@
            do
                case $i[1] in
                    (-)
                        minus+=( ${(M)books:#*${i:1}*} )
                        books=( ${books:#*${i:1}*} )
                    ;;
                    (*)
                        filter+=( ${(M)books:#*$i*} )
                    ;;
                esac
            done
            if [[ -z $filter && -n $minus ]]
            then
                filter=( ${books:|minus} )
            else
                filter=( ${filter:|minus} )
            fi
            if [[ -z $filter ]]
            then
                >&2 echo "books: no matches found (try book:list)"
                return 0
            else
                >&2 printf '\t%s\n' $filter
                get_pdfs $filter
            fi
        ;;
    esac
}
function issues() {
    typeset -aU issues
    typeset max i
    >&2 printf '%s' "finding most recent issue # ..."
    if ! max=${(M)$(2>/dev/null curl -fs https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues | gawk -v 'RS=href="' -F '"' \
                                                                                '$1 ~ /^[/]issues.*[0-9]$/{a=$1;exit}
                                                                                END{if(a){print a} else{exit 1}}')%%[0-9]#}
    then
        >&2 echo "couldn't determine what number the latest issue is."
        return 1
    fi
    >&2 echo "it's $max"
    if [[ $1 = all ]]
    then
        >&2 echo "Attempting to download all the issues, this may take a while ..."
        get_pdfs issues/{1..$max}
        return 0
    fi
    if [[ -n $latest ]]
    then
        issues+="issues/$max"
    fi
    for i in $@
    do
        if [[ $i -le $max ]]
        then
            issues+="issues/$i"
        else
            >&2 echo "issues/$i is larger than $max, ignoring"
        fi
    done
    if [[ -z $issues ]]
    then
        >&2 printf '\t%s\n' "there are no issues to download"
        return 0
    fi
    >&2 printf '\t%s\n' $issues
    get_pdfs $issues
    return 0
}
function get_pdfs() {
    typeset url i
    for i in $@
    do
        if ! url=$(2>/dev/null curl -fs "$baseurl$i/pdf" | \
            gawk -v 'RS=http-equiv="[rR]efresh".*[0-9 ;]*[uU][rR][lL]=' -F '"' \
            '$1 ~ /^http.*[.]pdf/{a=$1;exit}
            END{if(a){print a} else{exit 1}}')
        then
            >&2 echo "unable to extract url for $i"
            continue
        fi
        if [[ -e ${directory:+$directory[-1]/}${${url##*/}%%\?*} ]]
        then
            >&2 echo "looks like $i was already downloaded to ${directory:+$directory[-1]/}${${url##*/}%%\?*}"
            continue
        fi
        curl -f --create-dirs -o ${directory:+$directory[-1]/}${${url##*/}%%\?*} $url
    done
}
if ! zparseopts -D 'd:=directory'
then
    return 1
fi
if [[ -z $@ ]]
then
    >&2 printf '\t%s\n' \
        "[-d DIRECTORY]" \
        "[NUMBER] ... download issue by number" \
        "[latest] download most recent issue" \
        "[all] download all issues" \
        "[book:list] list all books" \
        "[book:WORD] ... download books matching WORD" \
        "[book:-WORD] ... don't download books matching WORD" \
        "[book:all] download all books" \
        "... no args specified, nothing to do ... exiting"
    return 0
fi
if [[ -n $directory ]]
then
    if ! mkdir -p $directory[-1]
    then
        return 1
    fi
    >&2 echo "files will be saved in $directory[-1]"
fi
for (( i=1; i<=${#@}; i++ ))
do
    case ${@[i]} in
        (all) all=all ;;            #download all standard issues
        (latest) latest=1 ;;            #download most recent issue
        (book:list) list_books=list ;;  #print a list of books
        (book:all) all_books=all ;;     #download all books
        (book:[[:alnum:]-]##) book+=( ${@[i]#*:} ) ;;   #download matching books (or books not matching if book:- is used)
        ([0-9]##) standard+=${@[i]} ;;          #download standard issue by number
        (*) ignore+=${@[i]} ;;          #tell user about unused args
    esac
done
if [[ -n $list_books || -n $all_books || -n $book ]]    #book argument was specified - get books
then
    books ${list_books:-${all_books:-$book}}
fi
if [[ -n $standard || -n $latest || -n $all ]]      #issue args - get issues
then
    issues $all $standard
fi
if [[ -n $ignore ]]
then
    >&2 printf '\t%s\n' "the following arguments were ignored:" $ignore
fi
return 0
```

There are a few comments toward the end of the script which hopefully explain the usage.

- valid issue related arguments include: `latest`, `all`, or a `NUMBER` – you may use shell expansion when calling the script to specify some range, eg. from bash/zsh, to download issues 12–15, specifying `{12..15}` should expand to the numbers 12 to 15
- valid book related arguments include: `book:list`, `book:all`, or `book:WORD` to match, `book:-WORD` to exclude, eg. `book:{begin,-3rd}` will download the "beginners" book series, except for the "3rd" one
- `-d DIR` option to output files into a specified directory
- any combination of args should work & invalid args are ignored
- doesn't try to resume a download, you could do that by adding the option `-C -` to the final `curl` command in `get_pdfs()`, and remove the `continue` from the file conflict test preceding that

I've probably missed something – use at your own risk!

---

An example to "follow" an html redirect using curl is found above in the function `get_pdfs()`:

```bsh
url=$(curl -fs <url_of_document_using_html_redirect> | \
    gawk -v \
    'RS=http-equiv="[rR]efresh" *content="[0-9 ;]*[uU][rR][lL]=' \
    -F '"' \
    '/^http/{print $1;exit}')
```

then, we should be able to download `"$url"`

Comment: feel free to update the Github ;-)
Thanks a lot, I will have a look to check it.